# C# :Find Date enclose in brackets in string

Tags: c#, regex, date

Hie there!

I am trying to find a work around to work with strings in c#

**Problem Statement**

I have text input as

`W.E.Power Dividend Total Return (Net 2%) vs. S&P 500 Total Return Index (11/30/1989 - 09/30/2009)`

and I need to replace the date in string with my date `11/05/1992-10/06/2013`.

**Current**

`get_pub_data` is input text

`string year_date = get_pub_data.Split(new char[] { '(', ')' })[1];`

so i used to get the content of brackets . But, then I encountered multiple brackets in a single line and hence the above code fails. As , it takes the 1st bracket encountered and replaces the bracket content with date and I get following result

**Wrong Output**

`W.E. Power Dividend Total Return (12/31/99 - 12/31/13) 
vs. S&P 500 Total Return Index (11/30/1989 - 09/30/2009)`

Instead of replacing `(date)` it replaces `(Net 2%)` with date

Comment: Are all your dates in that format?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes all of them are in same format `dd/MM/yyyy - dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: sounds like a bit of regex will get you out of your problem ... look at amir`s answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a regex here:

```
\(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s-\s\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\)
```

This will return you this:

```
(11/30/1989 - 09/30/2009)
```

For finding only dates use this:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

It will return you:

```
11/30/1989
```

And

```
09/30/2009
```

C# code example:

```
string str = "W.E.Power Dividend Total Return (Net 2%) vs. S&P 500 Total Return Index (11/30/1989 - 09/30/2009)";
string pattern = @"\(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s-\s\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\)";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, @"(01\01\2013 - 01\01\2014)"); // W.E.Power Dividend Total Return (Net 2%) vs. S&P 500 Total Return Index (01\01\2013 - 01\01\2014)
```

Comment: I used the Regex but can I get the value of index where it matches? I am trying to find the start and end index of the string to replace.

Comment: I think you can just use Regex.Replace()